# heap-use-after-free when using references with 2D vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am solving this problem on leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/

When I go to submit my solution, I get the error of `AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free`. More specifically, there is an error of `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` when I hit the line of code `currentMergedInterval = mergedIntervals.back();` but I don't understand why.

Whenever I modify the 2-D vector `mergedIntervals`, I make sure to update my vector reference, `currentMergedInterval`, after `mergedIntervals` has been modified. So it's not clear to me why this is causing an issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
        vector<vector<int>> mergedIntervals(1, intervals[0]);

        vector<int>& currentMergedInterval = mergedIntervals.back();

        int mergedIntervalEnd = 0;
        int intervalStart = 0;
        for (size_t i = 1; i < intervals.size(); i++)
        {
            mergedIntervalEnd = currentMergedInterval[1];
            intervalStart = intervals[i][0];
            
            if (mergedIntervalEnd >= intervalStart)
            {
                currentMergedInterval[1] = intervals[i][1];
            }
            else
            {
                mergedIntervals.push_back(intervals[i]);
                currentMergedInterval = mergedIntervals.back();
            }
        }
        
        return mergedIntervals;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Solution s = Solution();

    vector<vector<int>> v = {{1,3}, {2,6}, {8,10}, {15,18}};
    vector<vector<int>> sol = s.merge(v);

    // Expected output: [[1,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
    for (vector<int> vec : sol)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", vec[0], vec[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should merge the intervals in-place so it runs in constant space. If they didn't want you to modify `intervals` they should have made it `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References can't be reassigned. Assigning to a reference variable will not change the reference, it will change the object being referenced.

Because of this, and because of adding elements to a vector might invalidate all references, pointers or iterators to elements, the two statements

```
mergedIntervals.push_back(intervals[i]);
currentMergedInterval = mergedIntervals.back();
```

could lead to *undefined behavior* if the reference `currentMergedInterval` is now invalid.

For this specific case it would be better to use iterators or pointers instead of references, since they can be reassigned.

Answer (score 2):

You have made the mistake of thinking that

```
currentMergedInterval = mergedIntervals.back();
```

reassigns your reference. But this is not true, references can **never** be reassigned. Instead this code assigns `mergedIntervals.back()` to `mergedIntervals[0]` (the original referee of `currentMergedInterval`).

You could use a pointer (or an iterator) for the same purpose

```
vector<int>* currentMergedInterval = &mergedIntervals.back();
```

with consequent changes to the rest of your code.

But I think my preference would be to not add the current interval to the merged intervals until the end.

I.e.

```
   vector<vector<int>> mergedIntervals;
   size_t current = 0;

...

   mergedIntervals.push_back(intervals[current]);
   current = i;
...

   mergedIntervals.push_back(intervals[current]);
   return mergedIntervals;
```

again with consequent changes to the rest of your code